# Xcode Settings-Watch.bundle two way communication

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch

I would love a helping hand with an Xcode project that has an iPhone app and a watch app getting the Settings-Watch.bundle to communicate two ways between the settings page and the watch app.  At the moment it is only working one way. Any change to the value I make on the settings page is reflected in the app instantly, but it is not working back the other way. If I change the value in the watch app the settings page is not affected.

I have create a Settings-Watch.bundle and use some user defined defaults that I use throughout the watch app. One of the defaults is called `customGoalValue` contains a number and I would like this be be set from the settings page of the iPhone or the watch app. So in the root.plist for the settings bundle I created preference items for a text field and put the default item to 30, set the Identifier to customGoalValue. I set and registered the default value once in my watch app `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`

[image]

In the watch app I can load the default no problem by calling

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.my-name.my-app-name")
showCustomGoalValue = defaults.integer(forKey: "customGoalValue")
print(showCustomGoalValue)
```

If I change the number on the settings page of the iPhone, it changes immediately in the watch app. But if I try to chnange the value in the watch app, the settings page does not change.
I set the default by doing this

```
let newValue = 25
let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.my-name.my-app-name")
defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "customGoalValue") //Updates value no problem
defaults.synchronize() //Tried with and without this
let showCustomGoalValue = defaults.integer(forKey: "customGoalValue")
print(showCustomGoalValue) //Prints new value no problem
```

But then I take a look back at the iPhone settings app and it still says 30, when It should have changed to 25.

Is communication one way only?
Im using Xcode Version 11.4.1 (11E503a)
and Swift 5.1 I think